# Command-line autocompletion for python -m module

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

Is it possible to get command-line autocompletion of `python -m package.subpackage.module`?

This is similar to, but not the same as, `python ./package/subpackage/module.py`, which does autocomplete the directory and file paths. However with `-m`, python runs the library's module as a script with the appropriate namespacing and import paths.

I'd like to be able to do `python -m package.s[TAB]` and get autocompletion to `subpackage`.

Is this feature built in somewhere, or how can I set it up?

Comment: The bash-completion tool is extensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment section, you need to extend the **bash-completion** tool. Then, you'll create a script which handles the cases you need (ie: when the last argument was `-m`).

This little sample below shows a start for your custom completion script. Let's name it `python_completion.sh`.

```
_python_target() {
    local cur prev opts

    # Retrieving the current typed argument
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    # Retrieving the previous typed argument ("-m" for example)
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    # Preparing an array to store available list for completions
    # COMREPLY will be checked to suggest the list
    COMPREPLY=()

    # Here, we'll only handle the case of "-m"
    # Hence, the classic autocompletion is disabled
    # (ie COMREPLY stays an empty array)
    if [[ "$prev" != "-m" ]]
    then
        return 0
    fi

    # Retrieving paths and converts their separators into dots
    # (if packages doesn't exist, same thing, empty array)
    if [[ ! -e "./package" ]]
    then
       return 0
    fi

    # Otherwise, we retrieve first the paths starting with "./package"
    # and converts their separators into dots
    opts="$(find ./package -type d | sed -e 's+/+.+g' -e 's/^\.//' | head)"

    # We store the whole list by invoking "compgen" and filling
    # COMREPLY with its output content.
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$opts" -- "$cur"))

}

complete -F _python_target python
```

*(Warning. This script has a flaw, it won't work with filenames containing spaces)*. To test it, run it in the **current** environnement:

```
. ./python_completion.sh
```

And test it:

```
python -m packag[TAB]
```

[Here](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) is a tutorial to continue in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this exact thing, @Amessihel's answer was a very useful start.

I'm posting my solution which built upon it as I believe it could help others, especially if you want:

- a package autocomplete irrespective of your current path (which to me is one advantage of using -m)
- to preserve standard python autocompletion

```bash
# man page for "complete": https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man7/bash-builtins.7.html
_python_target() {
    local cur prev opts

    # Retrieving the current typed argument
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    # Retrieving the previous typed argument ("-m" for example)
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD - 1]}"

    # Preparing an array to store available list for completions
    # COMREPLY will be checked to suggest the list
    COMPREPLY=()

    # Here, we only handle the case of "-m"
    # we want to leave the autocomplete of the standard usage to the default,
    # so COMREPLY stays an empty array and we fallback through "-o default"
    if [[ "$prev" != "-m" ]]; then
        return 0
    fi

    # Ensure package exists
    PACKAGE_PATH=replace_this_by_your_package_path
    if [[ ! -e "$PACKAGE_PATH" ]]; then
        echo "$PACKAGE_PATH does not exist on your computer ?"
        return 0
    fi

    # Otherwise, first we retrieve all paths of folder and .py files inside the <your_package> package,
    # we keep only the package related section, remove the .py extension and convert their separators into dots
    opts="$(find $PACKAGE_PATH/your_package -type d -o -regex ".*py" | sed "s|$PACKAGE_PATH||" | sed "s|\.py||" | sed -e 's+/+.+g' -e 's/^\.//')"

    # Then we store the whole list by invoking "compgen" and filling COMREPLY with its output content.
    # To mimick standard bash autocompletions we truncate autocomplete to the next folder (identified by dots)
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$opts" -- "$cur" | sed "s|\($cur.[^.]*\).*|\1|" | uniq))
}

complete -F _python_target -o nospace -o bashdefault -o default python
# nospace disables printing of a space at the end of autocomplete,
# it allows to chain the autocomplete but:
# - removes the indication on end of chain that only one match was found.
# - removes the addition of the trailing / for standard python completion on folders
```